# OData .NET Core question about Task and ActionResult

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is the entire code of my controller class to manage classes (classroom actually, sorry for the confusion)

[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using My.Data;
using My.Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My.Api.Controllers
{
public class ClassesController : ODataController
{
    private readonly OygContext _context = new OygContext();

    /// <summary>
    /// GET: api/Classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns> 
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("Classes", RouteName = "GetClasses")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Class>>> GetClasses()
    {
        return Ok(await _context.Classes.ToListAsync());
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// GET: api/Classes/5
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet()]
    [ODataRoute("Classes({key})", RouteName = "GetClass")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Class>> GetClass([FromODataUri] Guid key)
    {
        var @class = await _context.Classes.FindAsync(key);

        if (@class == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(@class);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="class"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("Classes", RouteName = "PostClass")]
    public IActionResult PostClass([FromBody] Class @class)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        @class.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _context.Classes.Add(@class);
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //return CreatedAtAction("GetClass", new { id = @class.Id }, @class);
        return Created(@class);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DELETE: api/Classes/5
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpDelete()]
    [ODataRoute("Classes", RouteName = "DeleteClass")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Class>> DeleteClass(Guid id)
    {
        var @class = await _context.Classes.FindAsync(id);
        if (@class == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Classes.Remove(@class);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(@class);
    }

    private bool ClassExists(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Classes.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
}
```

The Microsoft documentation about OData a [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) but this is for OData .NET Standard I guess. What about .NET Core and OData Core? And, main question, what reference should I add to use IHttpActionResult? According to some other reading [I should add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package](https://forums.asp.net/t/2096814.aspx?Where%20do%20I%20find%20system%20web%20Http). Really? But I have some doubt because when I add it to my solution I get a resolution conflict with

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project
>   target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be
>   fully compatible with your
>   project.  Oyg.Api C:\Users\Public\Projects\oyg-server\Api\Oyg.Api.csproj  1

and

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what reference should I add to use IHttpActionResult?

For `IHttpActionResult`, it does not exist under .net core odata, you should use `ActionResult<Class>`. For more information, check [Migrate models and controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2#migrate-models-and-controllers).

> According to some other reading I should add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package. Really?

No, your project is .net core, you should not reference `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` which is resolved by `.NETFramework`.

For `HttpGet` error, you should delete `System.Web.Http`.

For more details about migrating .net odata to .net core odata, check the above link.